# GADT's - applications and usefulness?

Tags: haskell, gadt

I'm covering GADT's using learnyouahaskell and I'm interested in their possible uses. I understand that their main characteristic is allowing explicit type setting.

Such as:

```
data Users a where 
  GetUserName :: Int -> Users String
  GetUserId :: String -> Users Int

usersFunction :: Users a -> a 
usersFunction (GetUserName id) 
   | id == 100      = "Bob"
   | id == 200      = "Phil"
   | otherwise      = "No corresponding user"
usersFunction (GetUserId name)
   | name == "Bob"      = 100
   | name == "Phil"     = 200
   | otherwise          = 0

main = do
   print $ usersFunction (GetUserName 100)
```

Apart from adding additional type safety when working with these data types, what are the other uses of GADT's?

Comment: Constraints! The constraints you add on the constructors are enforced when you construct something and are available when you pattern match.

Comment: [This](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/With.pdf) paper talks about another use of GADTs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `Glambda`

Richard Eisenberg makes a very compelling case for GADTs in [`glambda`](https://github.com/goldfirere/glambda) a simply typed lambda calculus interpreter which uses GADTs to make sure ill-typed programs simply *cannot* be constructed. Phil Wadler has something similar and simpler [here](https://github.com/shayan-najd/MiniFeldspar/blob/master/Philip/GADT.hs), from which  the following sample was taken

```
data Exp e a where
  Con :: Int -> Exp e Int
  Add :: Exp e Int -> Exp e Int -> Exp e Int
  Var :: Var e a -> Exp e a
  Abs :: Typ a -> Exp (e,a) b -> Exp e (a -> b)
  App :: Exp e (a -> b) -> Exp e a -> Exp e b
```

The idea is that the type of the expression (in the interpreter) is encoded in the type of the expression as represented in the Haskell program.

### Vectors typed according to their lengths

By using GADTs, we can add a phantom type that tells us keeps track of the length of the vector we have. [This](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-1.4.3.1/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html) package has a nice implementation. This can be reimplemented in a bunch of ways (for example using `GHC.TypeLits` type-level natural numbers). The interesting data type (copied from the source of the package linked) is

```
data Vector (a :: *) (n :: Nat)  where
  Nil  :: Vector a Z
  (:-) :: a -> Vector a n -> Vector a (S n)
```

Then, I can write a safe version of `head' :: Vector a (S n) -> a`.

### Constraints

I don't have a good example demonstrating the usefulness of this, but you can tack on constraints to individual constructors in the GADT. The constraints you add on the constructors are enforced when you construct something and are available when you pattern match. This lets us do all sorts of fun stuff.

```
data MyGADT b where
  SomeShowable :: Show a => a -> b -> MyGADT b     -- existential types!
  AMonad :: Monad b => b -> MyGADT b
```