# Haskell AST with recursive types

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm currently trying to build a lambda calculus solver, and I'm having a slight problem with constructing the AST. A lambda calculus term is inductively defined as:

1) A variable

2) A lambda, a variable, a dot, and a lambda expression.

3) A bracket, a lambda expression, a lambda expression and a bracket.

What I would like to do (and at first tried) is this:

```
data Expr = 
    Variable
  | Abstract Variable Expr
  | Application Expr Expr
```

Now obviously this doesn't work, since Variable is not a type, and Abstract Variable Expr expects types. So my hacky solution to this is to have:

```
type Variable = String

data Expr = 
    Atomic Variable
  | Abstract Variable Expr
  | Application Expr Expr
```

Now this is really annoying since I don't like the Atomic Variable on its own, but Abstract taking a string rather than an expr. Is there any way I can make this more elegant, and do it like the first solution?

Comment: Your second definition which you find distasteful is the standard way to do this.  My advice is, get used to it.  You are thinking in a way that is not compatible with Haskell's type system, so go forth and train thyself.

Answer (score 3):

Your first solution is just an erroneous definition without meaning. `Variable` is not a type there, it's a nullary value constructor. You can't refer to `Variable` in a type definition much like you can't refer to any value, like `True`, `False` or `100`.

The second solution is in fact the direct translation of something we could write in BNF:

```
var  ::= <string>
term ::= λ <var>. <term> | <term> <term> | <var>
```

And thus there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

What you exactly want is to have some type like

```
data Expr 
  = Atomic Variable
  | Abstract Expr Expr
  | Application Expr Expr
```

But constrain first `Expr` in `Abstract` constructor to be only `Atomic`. There is no straightforward way to do this in Haskell because value of some type can be created by any constructor of this type. So the only approach is to make some separate data type or type alias for existing type (like your `Variable` type alias) and move all common logic into it. Your solution with `Variable` seems very ok to me.

But. You can use some other advanced features in Haskell to achieve you goal in different way. You can be inspired by [`glambda`](https://github.com/goldfirere/glambda) package which uses `GADT` to create typed lambda calculus. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39931015/2900502

I can come up with next solution to achieve you minimal goals (if you only want to constrain first argument of `Abstract`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data AtomicT
data AbstractT
data ApplicationT

data Expr :: * -> * where
    Atomic      :: String -> Expr AtomicT
    Abstract    :: Expr AtomicT -> Expr a -> Expr AbstractT
    Application :: Expr a -> Expr b -> Expr ApplicationT
```

And next example works fine:

```
ex1 :: Expr AbstractT
ex1 = Abstract (Atomic "x") (Atomic "x")
```

But this example won't compile because of type mismatch:

```
ex2 :: Expr AbstractT
ex2 = Abstract ex1 ex1
```

Comment: Fair enough, the expr solution maybe be possible if i make a function to check that every instance of (Abstract Expr Expr) has only an atomic value as the first Expr. Think I'll go with the second solution in my question however, as it seems to be the most popular.

Comment: @user2850249 You probably didn't see my second half of answer. If you use `GADT` you don't need to create function that checks that every `Abstract Expr Expr` has an atomic value as the first `Expr`. If you use non-atomic as first `Expr` your code just won't compile. And it is guaranteed in run-time that your first `Expr` will always be `Atomic`.